# Where to set versionCode and versionName since Gradle upgrade on android studio?

Tags: android, gradle

Since I upgraded Gradle it removed the `versionCode` and `versionName` properties from the gradle file on one of my app's libraries, but didn't remove them from my app's own gradle file.

Can anyone explain me why this happened? Can't I define version numbers for my library? Should I be setting my version numbers elsewhere?

Comment: Hi, Do you mean having them (automatically) set in BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE/VERSION_NAME ?

Comment: @gioravered i always had them in the gradle files for app and library. Basically I'm asking what's the best way of managing it. How does that BuildConfig thing work? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since gradle removed the versionCode & versionName for modules, I'm setting my module's (library) version code & version name like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion ...
    targetSdkVersion ...
    ...
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    buildConfigField("int", "VERSION_CODE", "${defaultConfig.versionCode}")
    buildConfigField("String","VERSION_NAME", "\"${defaultConfig.versionName}\"")
    ...
}
```

This will add the numbers to your BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE & BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME so apps that uses your library can know the library's version.

**EDIT**

Another way to completely avoid the use of `versionCode` and `versionName` is:

```
def VERSION_NAME="1.0.0"
def VERSION_CODE=1

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion ...
    targetSdkVersion ...
    ...
    buildConfigField("int", "VERSION_CODE", "${VERSION_CODE}")
    buildConfigField("String","VERSION_NAME","\"${VERSION_NAME}\"")
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is all fine, but AGP upgrade will still automatically remove them again. Any other place where to specify those so that they stick?

Comment: What do you mean remove them? `buildConfigField` is adding a variable to the BuildConfig.java and gradle does not remove anything from there.

Comment: As AGP upgrades remove fields from your configuration, I would have expected it to remove `versionCode` and `versionName` from your example, no? Or does it keep them if these are referenced in the `buildConfigField`?

Comment: It should work (it's working for me), But I will update the answer with another way to handle it.