# How to specify versionCode/versionName for Android libraries with Maven Publish

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project for a library. It's using an outdated Android Gradle Plugin version, and I am prompted by Android Studio to upgrade the plugin to the latest version. I have a module that is published to a (local) Maven repository, and I want to make sure that the module is still published to the repository after the upgrade.

When I let the AGP upgrade assistant do its job, I see diffs like the following:

```
diff --git a/build.gradle b/build.gradle
index e2cd93d..880db61 100644
--- a/build.gradle
+++ b/build.gradle
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
 plugins {
-    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
-    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
+    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
+    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
     id "co.uzzu.dotenv.gradle" version "2.0.0"
 }
```

```
diff --git a/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties b/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
index 082da6b..2041d30 100644
--- a/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
+++ b/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 #Thu Jun 09 22:24:26 CEST 2022
 distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
-distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
+distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
 distributionPath=wrapper/dists
 zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
 zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

This is all expected. However, since this is a library that I am versioning, AGP upgrade also [removes the `versionName` and `versionCode` from the `build.gradle` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76817368/agp-removes-version-from-libraries-build-gradle-where-to-put-library-version-pr). This is a problem because I want to keep the versioning of the library in the `build.gradle` file.

Unfortunately, the AGP upgrade assistant does not provide a way to keep the versioning in the `build.gradle` file because it does not make sense for libraries, so they claim.

This leads to an issue during the publish task `./gradlew example:publish`, which is using the `maven-publish` plugin, and this config:

```
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                groupId = 'com.example'
                version = android.defaultConfig.versionName
            }
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                url = "file://$projectDir/example"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This error appears:

```
> Configure project :example
Configuration 'debugCompileClasspath' was resolved during configuration time.
This is a build performance and scalability issue.
See https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2298
Run with --info for a stacktrace.
Configuration 'debugRuntimeClasspath' was resolved during configuration time.
This is a build performance and scalability issue.
See https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2298
Run with --info for a stacktrace.
Configuration 'releaseCompileClasspath' was resolved during configuration time.
This is a build performance and scalability issue.
See https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2298
Run with --info for a stacktrace.
Configuration 'releaseRuntimeClasspath' was resolved during configuration time.
This is a build performance and scalability issue.
See https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2298
Run with --info for a stacktrace.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':example:publishReleasePublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Cannot query the value of this property because it has no value available.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 578ms
```

Obviously, the `versionCode` and `versionName` are missing.

What can I do to prevent that?

I realize they are referenced to the `defaultConfig`, unlike what is shown in the [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html), where the version is hardcoded there. This again would prevent me from using the version code inside the application itself.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70057761/where-to-set-versioncode-and-versionname-since-gradle-upgrade-on-android-studio) where the solution is to simply add back the `versionName` and `versionCode` to the `build.gradle` file and reference them as build config fields.

However, I am looking for a more robust solution that does not break on an AGP upgrade.

Comment: Why you don't  want to assign it directly inside publications{ } block like version = "1.0.0"?

Comment: @ltp Like I wrote, "This again would prevent me from using the version code inside the application itself" (I actually meant the library … for logging etc.)

Comment: Oh, I get it now - making it available inside the java/kotlin class.  One way could be reading it from the generated versioning file?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? What is the "versioning file"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I actually meant to add a gradle script to generate a versioning file which you can read in your code. If I understood you correctly, you want to avoid using buildconfig fields. This could be an option. Similar to the approach used by jetpack lib and material component lib. 
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/dd8f6bebdd45c2875fab6574376a604a7d40061a/build.gradle#L219C1-L231C12

Comment: @ltp Interesting alternative, thanks. I can/want to use buildConfig fields — that's not the main issue. My problem is that the AGP upgrades remove the versionName/versionCode fields referenced in the build config. The given answer is a good enough workaround for that.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you should no longer use the `versionName` or `versionCode` in a library.

1. To still keep the version in the gradle file, you can define a custom extension variable e.g. `ext.library_version = "1.2.3"`. You can reference the variable directly in the publication script.
2. To reference library version from code, declare a `buildConfigField` and just assign it the value of custom variable. It will be available in the `BuildConfig`, the same as earlier the VERSION_NAME and VERSION_CODE.

Comment: That would probably work, yes, +1. Your answer would be even better if it contained a short code example!